# how to in middle of servlet execution send a page to user and continue execution after user submit the page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i want to to render a page in the middle of execution of servlet and continue
 the execution when the user submi the from and the renaming execution will use that page.can we do this please help me .

Answer (score 0):

make it two servlets, (or one servlet and differentiate 2 logic with a additional request param in form).

If you want variables in first servlet to be available in second servlet, use Session.

set is using

`request.getSession().setAttribute("name", var);`

and read it in second code using

`request.getSession().getAttribute("name");`

Comment: thanks for the solution but what i want my program will check user detail in database and if some filed is required then it will show pop up to user for filling that mandatory field only and after submiting  that field user will able to submit the form.

Comment: I still suggest you go with 2 requests, in your case I would fire an ajax request on submit to check for mandatory field, and on response of that request i will show popup if needed